# Why does hemagglutinin transfection fail in HEK293 cells?

Tags: influenza, transfection

I have tried to transfect HEK293 cells with the Influenza A H1N1 PR8 Hemagglutinin expression plasmid.
https://www.sinobiological.com/cdna-clone/h1n1-hemagglutinin-ha-vg11684-ch

I used PEI MAX as the transfection reagent.
After two days of transfection, I lysed the cells and performed SDS-PAGE and CBB staining, but there were always no bands representing hemagglutinin compared to negative controls (cell lysates without transfection).

I followed the protocol below.
The same protocol worked previously for a different plasmid expressing a different protein.

0. One day before the transfection experiment, I placed HEK293 cells in a 6-well plate to reach a confluence of 50~70% the next day.
1. Mix 3.5 µg of the plasmid in 150µl of DMEM without serum
2. Mix 11 µg of PEI Max in 150µl of DMEM without serum
3. Mix mixture 2 into mixture 1 and wait for 20 minutes at room temperature.
4. Aspirate the medium from the 6-well plate and wash with PBS
5. Add Mixture 3 to the 6-well plate
6. Place the plate in a 5% CO2 37°C incubator for 2 days.
7. After 2 days, aspirate the medium from the dish
8. Detach the cells using a cell scraper and suspend in ice-cold 2ml of PBS by pipetting
   (I have also tried detaching cells using trypsin, but it did not change the results.)
9. Centrifuge at 400g at 4°C for 5 minutes, and aspirate the supernatant
10. Resuspend in 1ml of ice-cold PBS
11. Centrifuge at 400g at 4C for 5min, and aspirate the supernatant
12. Resuspend in 100µl of RIPA buffer containing protease inhibitor cocktail
13. Vortex for 1 minute
14. Sonicate for 15 seconds
15. Keep on ice for 15 minutes
16. Centrifuge at 15,000g for 5 minutes at 4°C
17. Collect the supernatant
18. Perform SDS-PAGE and CBB-staining

Comment: How do you select for positively transformed cells?

Comment: I did not select positively transformed cells.

Comment: I performed transient transfection and lysed all cells on a plate.

Comment: So you have no control which cells where transfected?

Comment: Yes. I thought that there should be a band at about 60~70 kDa, which is the size of the protein. When I used a different plasmid, I could see the band.

Comment: Band after CBB-staining in step 18

Comment: “Yes. I thought that there should be a band at about 60~70 kDa, which is the size of the protein. When I used a different plasmid, I could see the band.” This might be confusing, but I don’t have positive controls.

Comment: I am asking about this because transfection efficiency is sometimes a problem. The plasmid carries a hygromycin resistance gene, I would select after the transfection. If this works, then there is another problem.

Comment: Selection by hygromycin sounds a good idea to check if there are cells that are successfully transfected.

Comment: Actually, it is not clear which is the problem: transfection, cell collection, or cell lysis. When I detached cells, I observed that cells adhered to the dish more strongly than the negative control or other plasmid-transfected cells. So, thinking that the cell collection method might be wrong, I tried trypsin and cell scraper, but the result did not change.

Comment: That's correct. The later two can easily be tested and optimized with any cell. In my experience these two rarely failed while transfection is more often a problem.